# Adding Metadata Attribute with white-space — Unix shell command

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, xattr

I'm trying to change a metadata attribute on a file, in a Node.js app, the problem is that I need to use white-space in the attribute value. I tried the following (used \ to add the white-space) but it did not work:

In the sample below, the *Musical Genre* should be **Hip Hop**.

`exec('xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemMusicalGenre "Hip\ Hop" PATH-TO-FILE')`

I also tried removing quotes (") or using template literals to wrap the script, but none of them worked. Would you please help me to find out how to sort this out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why you need exec ? can you just do `xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemMusicalGenre "Hip Hop" PATH-TO-FILE` ?

Comment: I missed to mention that it is in a Node.js app, I updated the question.

Comment: @Ogdila : Maybe you should then add a _nodejs_ tag, and remove the _bash_ tag, because, as far I can tell, _bash_ is not involved. The xattr command should be run by _sh_, so you _shell_ tag is OK.

Comment: I'd recommend you make xattr working in bash first, then try nodejs.

Comment: @Philippe I've also tested the script in bash but, unfortunately, it does not work if there is space in the value.

Comment: If it does not work in bash, then fix it first in bash, then nodejs.

Comment: @Philippe Sure. So do you happen to know what the issue might be that it is not working in the bash?

Comment: PATH-TO-FILE, is this mp4 file ? a text file ? can you paste a sample ?

Comment: @Philippe This is an mp3 file.

Comment: @Philippe The script works fine without space, this issue is only when there is a space in the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212796/discussion-between-philippe-and-ogdila).

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts?